# Virtual Box: Critical error while running the virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, opensuse, ubuntu-14.04

I use a VirtualBox machine as a local web server (this is an Open Suse VM). But for a few days, problems occurs with my VM.

First, I can't delete my oldest snapshot, the reason is:

```
Result Code: NS_RROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component:   SessionMachine
Interface:   IMachine {480cf695-2d8d-4256-9c7c-cce4184fa048}
```

Another issue came today:

```
VirtualBox - Guru Meditation

A critical error has occurred while running the virtual machine and machine
execution has been stopped.

[...]

Press OK if you want to power off the machine of press Ignore if you want
to leave it as for debugging. Please note that debugging requires special
knowledge and tools, so it is recommended to press OK now.
```

It's pretty painful, because, it's the third time it happens, and I can't work on my web server...

[Here is the link to the VirtualBox log file](http://www.datafilehost.com/d/d9c7f324)

Note that, I just upgraded my Lubuntu from 12.10 to 14.04 (I got problems during this upgrade -- blank screen when I was booting, but I fixed them). Open Suse is running on my VM, and I use Interbase, PHP, Apache. The first time the issue happened, I was using Netbeans, then it was when I was using Kwrite. I previously got many networks problems with this VM (it's the reason why I take snapshots to avoid rebooting).

Why am I receiving critical errors when attempting to run the virtual machine?

Comment: Try adding more information. What have you tried to do, state the problem specifically, what are you doing with the software, etc.

Comment: The log isn't availabe any longer, but most such cases relate to `VCPU0: Guru Meditation -2403 (VERR_TRPM_DONT_PANIC)`, which usually indicates lack of `VT-x` support on your CPU (refer to [VirtuaBox forum](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=86869)  for more info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created another VM and the problem doesn't appear more.

Answer (score 28):

Today I got the same error message, and resolved it by closing the Android Emulator that was also running.

Comment: This was my issue. Perfect! Thanks.

Comment: Same for me as well. Wasted hours on this

Comment: mine here by terminating the processes related to virtual-manager such as virtrd.

Comment: That was the issue. It worked. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I've figured the answer. 99 Percent of the cases including me will have the same solution. We have assigned more memory for the VM so the Host system does not have enough memory to handle VM. You can get rid of Guru meditation by assigning less memory to the VM. you can do this by: Open Vm>Settings>System> And reduce assigned memory to a lesser value.

Hope it helps.

Comment: VM has 1GB of memory, and the host has 6GB, so I'm in 1% with the critical error :)

Comment: Does your PC have virtualization support? Check whether you have  'Falling back to raw-mode: VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes' in your log. If so, you've to change BIOS settings. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39542853/enable-vt-x-in-your-bios-security-settings-refer-to-documentation-for-your-comp/39542859
@AntonK

Comment: you're right - my CPU (Celeron Dual Core T3500) doesn't have VT-x support, and it is not possible to enable this in BIOS. So the newer versions of VirtualBox will probably stop working on my hardware in the end... This issue is explained at the [VirtualBox forum](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=86869).

Answer (score 6):

i was facing this error and tried that and worked for me

1- Open VM VirtualBox

2- file -> Settings -> System -> Processor

3- Check Extended Features : Enable PAE/NX .

Comment: If `Enable PAE/NX` is not checked, you won't be able to boot the kernel (the error "_This kernel requires the following features not present on the CPU: pae_" is shown). So you won't reach the critical error...

Answer (score 2):

VBox linux machines allow 128MB video memory at max, by default. If you have ever tweaked the video memory to 256MB then this error might occur. For me this error came after few days of the tweak to 256MB video memory. When I turned it back to 128MB(default), now the critical error(Guru Meditation) is gone.
This was what happened with me.

Comment: This worked for me. Also, I had 256MB for a few months before the error, and the error popped up only when the VM was loading while dragging the screen to another monitor.

Comment: Great!! Finally ur the one that matched my scenario I guess. :)

Answer (score 2):

I have got same problem (GURU meditation ERROR..) while trying to install windows 10 in VM box ..
I just [image: On Acceleration menu]

and Lower RAM usage to (half),and Done!.
This may Help!..

Trying Reinstallation and Go to Repair of VirtualBox also may Help !!...

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the Guru Meditation error appeared every time I tried to update my Lubuntu 18.04 machine, in VirtualBox 6.04. It was associated with the following Vbox.log error:

```
00:04:13.601 Not in text mode!
00:04:13.601 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Following the suggestion described here: [Not in Text Mode! Error (guest Windows PE 3.0)](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=44208), about *activating I/O APIC in the virtual machine configuration*, the problem was solved.

Answer (score -1):

VBox linux machines allow 128MB video memory at max, by default. If you have ever tweaked the video memory to 256MB then this error might occur. For me this error came after few days of the tweak to 256MB video memory. When I turned it back to 128MB(default), now the critical error(Guru Meditation) is gone.