# Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings (refer to documentation for your computer)

Tags: android, android-studio, haxm

While I was adding a virtual device in my Android Studio, Android Studio is Showing This Error. See This Image:
[image]
.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

[image]

shutdown you pc and open bios settings, and enable Virtual Technology-x option and restart your pc.

done.

Comment: How do I open Bios Settings?

Comment: it depend on system.

Comment: which laptop you have? or if you have desktop then which motherboard do u have

Comment: I got these Setting Thanks

Comment: press escape while starting for hp laptop

Answer (score 16):

**In Short -> You must enable VT-x Technology in your BIOS**.

Here are the detailed steps:

**1- Restore Optimized Defaults (Not Necessary)**`//Steps to start BIOS`

Its better to restore Optimized Defaults before, But **following steps are not necessary:**

1. Reboot the computer and open the system's BIOS menu. This can usually be done by pressing the delete key, the F1 key or Alt and F4 keys depending on the system.
2. Select Restore Defaults or Restore Optimized Defaults, and then select Save & Exit.

**2- Enable VT-x Technology in BIOS (Necessary)**

1. Power on/Reboot the machine and open the BIOS (as per Step 1).
2. Open the Processor submenu The processor settings menu may be hidden in the Chipset, Advanced CPU Configuration or Northbridge.
3. Enable Intel Virtualization Technology (also known as Intel VT-x) or AMD-V depending on the brand of the processor. The virtualization extensions may be labelled Virtualization Extensions, Vanderpool or various other names depending on the OEM and system BIOS.
4. Select Save & Exit.

**Note:** Many of the steps above may vary depending on your motherboard, processor type, chipset and OEM. Refer to your system's accompanying documentation for the correct information on configuring your system.

**Test:**

Run `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep vmx svm`. If the command outputs, the virtualization extensions are now enabled. If there is no output your system may not have the virtualization extensions or the correct BIOS setting enabled.

Detailed instructions can be found [Here](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Virtualization_Guide/sect-Virtualization-Troubleshooting-Enabling_Intel_VT_and_AMD_V_virtualization_hardware_extensions_in_BIOS.html)

Comment: Thanks Milad But I Cannot vote as I Have less Reputation

Comment: How can I do that in wondows 10

Answer (score 9):

Even i have enable VT-X tech and disabled secure boot. My Android Studio failed to load emulator saying `dev/kvm not found`.

**After doing some research on this. Finally i solved it out.**

This issue came after updating HAXM. I found some useful answers. which tell this issue is in HAXM 7.2.0. See [this issue on github](https://github.com/intel/haxm/issues/56)

Steps to solve:

- Uninstall Haxm from SDK manager.
- Download previous version of HAXM v7.1.0 from [this release page](https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases).
- Install this HAXM.

Now everything should work fine as before.

Comment: I had VT-X enabled too, but I'd still keep getting OP's error. This is the solution that worked for me.

Comment: I installed HAXM v7.6.5 directly from the link above and fixed the problem as well.

Answer (score 2):

It was because of docker which uses hyper-v. You just have to remove hyper-v from windows features.

Answer (score 2):

**No restart, no BIOS needed in my case**. I have downloaded and installed the latest version of `HAXM` from the releases: [HAXM releases](https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases)

Answer (score 1):

Even after enabling Intel Virtualization Technology (Intel VT-x), I got the error message ' dev/kvm not found ' in Android Studio.by making Hyper-V feature off in Windows 8.1 issue was fixed.

here is how to access Windows Hyper-V feature

Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on and off.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make it simple:
The solution is just to enable vt-x or Virtualization Technology in bios, which is under Advanced Tab.  and once it's enabled, the error disappears.[image: Screenshot of bios]

FYI
I had similar issues starting up my Android emulators in Appium studio for my mobile testing, and on top, I had latest bios, which looked so different to the standard one.
So attaching screenshot of my computer bios, but the option should be there on any Bios settings.  Just need to boot the computer, and push Esc or some function key to see the computer bios, and then find the correct option to enable it under Advanced Tab, (most importantly, you may have to scroll down as the option would be down the list)
I left my Hyper-V feature as is, which was enabled though.

Answer (score 1):

HP computer method:

Make sure your BIOS is updated before changing the settings. If you have an HP computer, they have an [HP Support Assistant app](https://www8.hp.com/us/en/campaigns/hpsupportassistant/hpsupport.html?jumpid=va_r602_us/en/any/psg/pl_ot_ob_ds_pd/hpsupportassistant_cc/dt) you can configure to automatically install BIOS updates. Then follow the [instructions on how to update BIOS](https://support.hp.com/my-en/document/c00007682).

Then you can look up which HP computer for how to change the BIOS in a search engine.

For an HP ZBook, follow these steps:

1. Restart your computer with the shift key pressed (before you click restart) until a menu appears.
2. Choose BIOS Setup on the screen (or press F10).
3. Click on Troubleshoot.
4. Using your arrow keys in this menu, go to Advanced Options.
5. Select UEFI Firmware Settings.
6. Select restart.
7. It reboots into a Startup menu
8. Choose BIOS Setup
   With arrow keys go to Advanced tab.
9. Choose the System Options.
10. Check both the Virtualization Technology (VTx) and the Virtualization Technology for Directed I/O (VTd) boxes.
11. Go back to the Main tab and at bottom choose Save and Exit.
12. Computer will restart.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac users, see this answer:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/47414989/2788608

Essentially, your OS may be blocking Intel from running what it needs to get your AVD going. Go into `System Preferences -> Security and Privacy` and you should see an option there to enable the Intel processes. Restart Android Studio and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues and below is how i fixed it:

- Restart your PC, when booting up `press f10` key to select or open BIOS Settings.
- Locate and check / enable `Virtual Technology-x` option under Device Configuration Settings
- Save changes, system restart.
- All should be working fine now

Answer (score 0):

Check "Virtualization" status under performance option in your task manager. If you already have enabled it in your BIOS and still status is "Disabled", then go to bios, disable it and save & exit. Restart or shut down again. Enable it in BIOS again and save & exit. This time you'll see the status changed to "Enabled", It took me 3 attempts (don't know why it took that much time, but finally it worked).

Answer (score 0):

I guess the same error happened to me after I installed Docker. The solution below worked for me:

1. Go to `Turn Windows features on and off`
2. Uncheck the `Hyper-V` checkbox

[image]

3. Uninstall `Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager` via `Programs and Features`. After the uninstall process, restart your computer (trying to install a new release of HAXM without rebooting didn't work for me).
4. Go to [HAXM GitHub](https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases) page and download the release. I downloaded `HAXM v7.6.5`.
5. Install HAXM

After all these steps, everything is fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD.
VT-x is disabled in BIOS.

Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings (refer to documentation for your computer).this error on android studio 
I dont no how to do Bios Security