# How to enable VT-x in BIOS for x86 windows to run emulator

Tags: android

I am trying to run virtual device on my x86 windows PC. But it is asking to enable VT-x to run emulator.[This is what is prompted on running the app from emulator.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sv47p.png)

Comment: Check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39542853/enable-vt-x-in-your-bios-security-settings-refer-to-documentation-for-your-comp/39542859

Comment: The details vary by PC manufacturer. You will need to look up documentation for your PC to determine how to get into the BIOS settings (e.g., press `<F12>` on the hardware boot screen) and where in there the relevant Intel or AMD CPU settings are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow these steps to fix your problem:

1. Restart your computer
2. Open BIOS ( search for your Manufacture computer type on internet) or press (possibly some variation, but give these a try first):

   ```
   Dell:   F2 
   HP:     F10 
   Acer:   F2
   Asus:   F2 
   Toshiba:F2
   Lenovo: F1 (or F2)
   ```
3. Use the arrow keys to choose the configuration and then search for Virtual technology - sometimes called Intel VTx.
4. Enable it
5. Exit and save the changes in configuration.

Answer (score 0):

1. shutdown your pc
2. and open bios setting

[check here for windows-10](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/access-bios-windows-10)

3. and enable Virtual Technology-x option
4. and restart your pc