# Minikube Error - Error starting host: Temporary Error: Error configuring auth on host: OS type not recognized

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I'm trying to setup a Kubernetes cluster in local machine using `minikube` in Windows environment and I'm getting this error

[image]

Any idea why I get this error?

Answer (score 1):

Please enable `VT-x` on your computer BIOS.

For reference:

> https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/
>
> [Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings (refer to documentation for your computer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39542853/enable-vt-x-in-your-bios-security-settings-refer-to-documentation-for-your-comp)